# Mongoose doesn't save data while reporting them being saved

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a problem saving some data to Mongo using mongoose.

In my database module I'm doing:

```
  self.addMove = function (gameId, move, callback) {
    Game.findById(gameId, function (err, game) {
      if (err)
        callback(err);
      else {
        game.newMove = move; //apply new move
        game.save(Game.transformState(callback)); //save the game
      }
    });
  };
```

where newMove is defined as virtual method in GameSchema as

```
GameSchema.virtual('newMove').set(function (move) {
  if (move.player !== move.piece[0])
    return;
  if (allowedMove(move)) { //if piece is allowed to move
    var from = positionToIndex(move.from),
      to = positionToIndex(move.to);
    this._field[to] = this._field[from]; //move it
    this._field[from] = "";
  }
});
```

and transformState as static method

```
GameSchema.statics.transformState = function (callback) {
  return function (err, data) {
    if (err)
      callback(err);
    else
      callback(null, {
        _id: data._id,
        moves: data.moves,
        field: data.field //data.field transforms 1D array into 2D client-useable array
      });
  };
};
```

How I call addMove:

```
socket.on('addMove', function (msg) {
  console.log('New move: ' + msg);
  var msg = JSON.parse(msg);
  db.addMove(msg._id, msg.move, function (err, data) {
    if(!err)
      io.emit('getState', JSON.stringify(data));
  });
});
```

As requested, my GameSchema:

```
GameSchema = new Schema({
  moves: [MoveSchema],
  _field: {
    type: [String],
    default: ["WR", "WN", "WB", "WQ", "WK", "WB", "WN", "WR", "WP", "WP", "WP", "WP", "WP", "WP", "WP", "WP", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BR", "BN", "BB", "BQ", "BK", "BB", "BN", "BR"]
  }
})
```

And as a bonus, this is how I request game state second time:

```
//sockets.js
socket.on('getState', function (msg) {
  console.log('User requested game state!');
  var msg = JSON.parse(msg);
  db.getGame(msg._id, function (err, data) {
    if(!err)
      io.emit('getState', JSON.stringify(data));
  });
});

//database.js
self.getGame = function (id, callback) {
  Game.findById(id, Game.transformState(callback));
};
```

As you can see, each time I get new move from client I modify current game field and save that game. When I save it with `game.save(Game.transformState(callback));` it is "saved" which means data in callback are correct. But if I try to request game state again, I can see it's not saved. I also tried checking MongoDB manually and indeed is not saved. What I'm trying to explain is that in line `game.save(Game.transformState(callback));` function `callback` is executed with updated game state and I can see it on client but the state is actually not saved in database.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but are you expecting your `newMove` virtual to be saved? Because virtuals don't get persisted and you're missing some `this.set` calls in your method in comparison to [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html). And what is `callback`? How are you calling `addMove(...)`?

Comment: @Tony Yes, I expected to do it as seen in [guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) (search for mad.name.full = 'Breaking Bad';) but it seems it's not working. I just tried what you suggested and I swaped ``game.newMove = move;`` for ``game.set('newMove', move);`` and behaviour is still the same. Then I tried dropping virtual all together and use ``game._field[to] = game._field[from];   game._field[from] = "";`` but the change still isn't saved.

Comment: @Tony Callback is function I pass to database method from sockets controller method and it expects two parameters: (err, data). I modified OP and added code where I call database method.

Comment: I've added Schema and some bonus code if you find anything wrong there. I'll try what you suggested. Is it possible something is wrong with compose.io, since I'm not using local mongoDB? I'd guess not because I can update other documents but just so that you know...

Comment: Check out the first `Q`: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html

Comment: I figured it out, check my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, mongoose doesn't detect field was changed if you modify arrays directly. To trigger detection I used `this.markModified('_field');`

There are some other methods to do this I found out later:
[Mongoose: assign field of type 'array of Strings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423508/mongoose-assign-field-of-type-array-of-strings)

Comment: When I saw your schema I knew.